# Scikit-learn random forest tree - how to interpret 'samples' and 'values'?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

I've made a random forest with the scikit learn package (python). However, when showing the trees, there seems to be something wrong. 
The total samples per node is not the sum of the values. Also, the values associated with the position in the list of values does not seem to correspond with the class label it assigns itself to.

Anyone any ideas? Thank you in advance.

[Click here for sample tree (png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8moHU.png)

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I am curious.

Answer (score 0):

You star with 64 samples and all your terminating nodes have a total of 64 samples. The terminating nodes don't have to be at the same level, in this case three of the terminating nodes have enough information after two decisions, but two of them need a third one.

Whenever a node splits the samples are split in two new nodes, which combined have the same amount of samples as the parent.

Comment: Thank you, that is clear. A question however that remains is what 'value = [....] ' means. Do you know it?